# ARP request not broadcast to local network with TL-WR481N

Tags: networking, router, arp

I want to run a server on my local network. It is a machine running NixOS and using the static IP 192.168.0.16. All other devices use DHCP.

The server is called M, my laptop is called S (192.168.0.150).

#### What's wrong?

Devices in the network can't see each other. Using wireshark, I see that when I ping the server from my laptop, the laptop sends an ARP request "Who has 192.168.0.16? Tell 192.168.0.150" as a broadcast. This ARP request never reaches my server, and the laptop does not get any answer.

It is the same from the server, the ARP request is not broadcasted.

#### What works?

- `ping localhost` works on both machines
- `ping 192.168.0.1` (router/gateway IP) works on both machines
- both machines have normal access to the internet
- `ip r` output on M (similar on S):

```bash
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wls1 proto static 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wls1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.16
```

- `ip a` output on M:

```bash
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:2a:14:0d:5d:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wls1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:2a:60:dd:a0:fd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp3s0
    inet 192.168.0.16/24 scope global wls1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::462a:60ff:fedd:a0fd/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

The problem has been weird in that sometimes pings & access works as expected. I couldn't document it perfectly, but it "feels" like sometimes two devices in the network can't see each other (while the others can). The router model is `TL-WR481N v14`.

Comment: If an answer has helped you solve your problem feel free to mark the answer as accepted and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can test it by assigning static IPs and then disconnecting both M and S from the router and connecting them to each other directly with a network cable.

After you do that, assuming the issue is gone, connect the router again but keep using static IP addresses. If the issue is gone it means it is DHCP-related.

Answer (score 0):

I set the router to restart every day, and that solved the problem (mostly). If it occurs again, I restart the router. Maybe not a nice solution, but it works.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.